# Fourier Transform of Absolute Value

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

If you ask Mathematica to provide the Fourier Transform of a singular functions it is likely to provide an answer that while *nearly* correct, is technically incorrect and it will do so without a word of warning. Are there any ways to guard for this other than telling the user to beware?

Below I show what happens when you ask for the Fourier Transform of the absolute value function.

Mathematica defines the Fourier transform, $F(\omega)$, of the function $f(t)$, to be:
$$F(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty Exp({i w t})\ f(t)\ dt
$$ which is a standard normalization. If you ask for the Fourier Transform of $|t|$,

```
FourierTransform[Abs[t], t, w]
```

Mathematica returns: 
$$F(w)=-\frac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{w^2}$$ which is fine except at $w=0$ where it gives $F(0)=-\infty$. For $w=0$ we have, by definition,
$$F(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| \ dt = +\infty \ .$$

Thus it is WAY OFF at $w=0$. The correct transform is of the form:

$$
A \delta(w) - \frac{\sqrt{2/\pi}}{w^2}
$$
where $A$ is a divergent integral. I expect that $|t|$ is not the only function for which Mathematica returns an incorrect Fourier Transform with no warning.

Comment: Usually GenerateConditions should work for this kind of thing. However, at least on V9 `FourierTransform[Abs[t], t, w, GenerateConditions -> True]` returns unevaluated

Comment: With v10: `SameQ @@ FourierTransform[{Abs[t], t Sign[t], Sqrt[t^2], Piecewise[{{-t, t < 0}, {t, t >= 0}}]}, t, w]` returns `True`. Although, using `GenerateConditions -> True` evaluates with `t Sign[t]`; however, returns the same result, i.e., no conditions.

Comment: Using the identity $|t|=\int_0^t Sign[s] ds$ with GenerateConditions also returns unevaluated. I am using Version 10.0.1.0.

Comment: The identity $$|t| = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1-\cos{\alpha t}}{\alpha^2}\ d\alpha$$ with GenerateConditions also returns unevaluated. It gives the same result as $|t|$ for the transform.

Comment: The last identity can be used to obtain the correct transform. Insert it into the definition of the transform and switch the order of integration will yield an additional term $\propto \delta(\omega) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d\omega'}{\omega'^2}$

Comment: `FourierTransform[Abs[t], t, w]` does not exist as a usual Fourier transform because `Abs[t]` is not integrable over (−∞,∞). Also see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), formula 311. Kammler, David (2000), A First Course in Fourier Analysis, Prentice Hall, presents this formula in Appendix A-6 without any reference. Erdélyi, Arthur, ed. (1954), Tables of Integral Transforms, 1, McGraw-Hill. does not contain it.

Comment: The FT as given is correct. I don't have Kammler handy now (maybe later if I go into the office) but I'm pretty sure that text shows how to handle these generalized cases (that is, ones that fall outside the integral definition).

Comment: Also, the claim in the original post about the behavior at `w-0` is off base. This FT is not defined as an integral, so one cannot base a correct argument on how the integral definition of the FT might behave.

Comment: The correct result is actually $ \frac{\pi^2\delta(w)^2-\frac1{w^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$

Comment: No, the correct interpretation is the Fourier transform in the sense of distributions. The result is then an Hadamard finite part https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765751/what-is-the-fourier-transform-of-x. There is no Dirac involved.

Answer (score -1):

Here there is an explanation of why you can dismiss the "missing part", don't really know if is fully mathematically rigurous, but it "sees" right:
https://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/absT.php
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is more appropriate for a comment than an answer. I suggest improving this answer with some code and to also make it “self contained” that is, to not rely on an external link that may, at some point, go dead.

Comment: Could you explain how to obtain the result of `InverseFourierTransform[-Sqrt[2/Pi]/w^2,w,t]`?

Comment: Here there is an explanation of why you can dismiss the "missing part", don't really know if is fully mathematically rigurous, but it "sees" right: https://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/absT.php Hope this helps. (I move it to a comment as indicated by @CATrevillian).
I will put what is done in the link, but without proving its validity (its look right to me anyway):
1. first note that $|t| = t\theta(t) - t\theta(t)$ with $\theta(t)$ the unitary step function.

Comment: 2. note that the fourier transform of $\pm t \theta(\pm t)$ equals $\frac{-1}{(2\pi f)^2}+\frac{\delta '(\pm f)}{2}$, so when added to form the fourier transform of $|t|$ the result is $\frac{-1}{2\pi^2 f^2}+\frac{1}{2}(\delta '(f) +\delta '(-f))$, so the rest is to prove that the second part is zero.

Comment: 3. They use a property that says that a Dirac's delta function can be defined as a function series $F_n(t) = \begin{cases} n \text{ , for } \frac{-1}{2n}\leq t \leq \frac{1}{2n} \\ 0 \text{ , else} \end{cases}$ which have area equal to 1, so $\delta(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n(t)$.

Comment: 4. Then, they explain that $\frac{dF_n(\pm t)}{dt} = \pm (n \delta(t +\frac{1}{2n})-n \delta(t -\frac{1}{2n}))$ (here using that $F_n(t)$ can be represented using $\theta(t)$ and also that $\delta(t) = \frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}$), so $\frac{dF_n(t)}{dt} +\frac{dF_n(-t)}{dt} =0$, so in the limit is prove that $\delta'(t) + \delta'(-t) =0$.

Comment: In your argument it is enough to say that $\delta(x)$ is even and $\delta'(x)$ is odd. By the way, you should embed your comments into the answer.

Comment: @yarchik I don't know if "knowing" they are odd is enough, since are not functions, and distributions are more complicated mathematical objects. Maybe you can explained better.  I don't answer it because I first left the link, were someone else give the explanation. Also, I don't have enough mathematical background to prove is his results is "formaly" right/rigorous, but it seems right to me. I left it in the comments following the request of CA Trevillian and user64494, wanting to help user64494. Best regards.